# How to write a function to return deserialized struct from a toml file?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, serde, toml

I want to return de-serialized rust struct of type `ConfigModel` from a function. Where the struct is *lifetime-annotated* and defined something like this:

```
// i can change this struct
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct ConfigModel<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub a_field: Inner<'a>,
}

// i *can't* change this struct definition
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Inner<'a> {
    pub inner_field: &'a str,
}
```

The data is deserialized from a `String` using the `toml` crate.
I am wondering how I can make this possible.

Below is code I was testing with:

```
pub fn get_config<'a>() -> Result<ConfigModel<'a>, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    println!("Retrieving TOML config");
    let default_config = std::fs::read_to_string("./my_file.toml")?;

    Ok(toml::from_str(&default_config)?)
}
```

This result in following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `default_config`
 --> examples/utils/tst.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     Ok(toml::from_str(&default_config)?)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------^^^
  |     |                 |
  |     |                 `default_config` is borrowed here
  |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I also try to return with `'static` lifetime, but am hitting the same wall. I am wondering if it is possible to make a helper function to return the deserialized struct data.

Comment: Using a reference in your `ConfigModel` means the object you're returning doesn't own the data for `some_field`, who does? Pondering that may make you realize that you actually want `String` instead of `&str`.

Comment: @kmdreko is it possible to return a struct with a `&str` field from a function? I was able to test and confirm that it works fine if I don't encapsulate the logic  as part of a function.

Comment: If you were to ponder the ownership at play and re-read the error, what you're returning is referencing data in `default_config`. However, encapsulating it into a function means that `default_config` is destroyed when you want to return (and presumably use) the parsed structure. It may work elsewhere if the `default_config` were kept in scope while the `ConfigModel` was used. You can fix it by using `String` instead of `&str` and removing the lifetime so that your object is not referencing the original string.

Comment: I updated my question above. what if I am using a nested struct, but I cannot update the implementation of the inner struct (`Inner` in this case)?

Comment: Ah, that's a bit trickier. Is `Inner` from a crate then? If you divulge what you're deserializing there may be alternatives.

Comment: yep, its from my own crate, but I'm using it in two scenarios (both in tests and in lib). so it works for now if I keep all the struct fields as they are, though I'd rather not change how the struct is implemented just so I am able to add a helper function for test/example purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like I've managed to put together a working version based on what ***[@Caesar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73381857/10237506)*** had hinted at. **Huge thanks to him again** for pointing me in the right direction - this is why I love the Rust community, as I am continuously amazed and seems like I learn something new each day.

Now just to recap, my end goal here was to create a *single helper function* that can return to me the (deserialized) struct data from a TOML config file. Towards this end, I understood that there is a way to convert the `String` result that I get from `read_to_string()` into a borrowed `&str` value, which then finally allows me to return a lifetime-annotated `ConfigModel<'a>` from the helper function.

As mentioned in the linked answer, I was able to achieve this by harnessing the `Box::leak(Some_String.into_boxed_str())` idiomatic approach, which actually had not even crossed my mind, as I did not consider that something like this was possible in Rust to even begin with.

Now that said, my full code at present looks like this:

```rust
pub fn get_config<'a>() -> Result<ConfigModel<'a>> {
    println!("Retrieving TOML config");

    let default_config: &'a str =
        Box::leak(std::fs::read_to_string("./my_file.toml")?.into_boxed_str());

    Ok(toml::from_str(default_config)?)
}
```

And in my examples and tests, here's how I'm using it:

```rust
mod utils;
use utils::get_config;

// in my actual case, I am defining this type elsewhere
pub type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let cfg = get_config()?;
    println!("{cfg:#?}");

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, I'd like to show you a problem that might make you abandon this approach entirely:

```rust
toml::from_str::<ConfigModel<'_>>("[a_field]\ninner_field = \"as\\ndf\"")?;
```

yields

> Error: invalid type: string "as\ndf", expected a borrowed string for key `a_field.inner_field` at line 2 column 15

i.e. you cannot deserialize valid YAML strings which contain an escape sequence into a `&str`. The standard way around this is to replace `&'a str` by `Cow<'a, str>` (or just use `String`). But if you do so, your problem vanishes: you can always construct a `ConfigModel<'static>` from a `ConfigModel<'a>`:

```rust
ConfigModel {
    a_field: Inner {
        inner_field: toml::from_str::<ConfigModel<'_>>(&self.0)?
            .a_field
            .inner_field
            .into_owned()
            .into(),
    },
}
```

I suspect that the config files don't contain strings so long that you'd need to worry about the memory usage of this.
But if you really can't modify `Inner`, this might spell trouble.

---

Now to answer your question: you can return `ConfigModel` from a function. But it needs a place in memory where a `String` can be stored that it can know will outlive the `ConfigModel` it returns. So, storing `default_config` on the stack of `get_config` with `let default_config = read_to_string(…)?` definitely won't work. You also can't return both the `String` and the `ConfigModel` at once, because that'd constitute moving a self-referential structure. Storing the `String` on the stack of the function that calls `get_config`  works, but isn't particularly pretty.
The pattern I use in this situation is to encapsulate this somewhat cleanly is this: I define a new struct that holds the `String` and does the config file reading:

```rust
pub struct ConfigReader(String);
impl ConfigReader {
    fn read() -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self(std::fs::read_to_string("./my_file.toml")?))
    }
}
```

deserializing the config can then be done easily:

```rust
impl ConfigReader {
    fn deserialize(&'_ self) -> Result<ConfigModel<'_>> {
        Ok(toml::from_str(&self.0)?)
    }
}
```

You pay for this at the call site, where you need two variables instead of one:

```rust
let config = ConfigReader::read()?;
let config = config.deserialize()?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72b8db238559470071de5e7119cf7d0e)
(There are some variations to this, e.g., you can make the first function infallible and do the file reading in the second function by storing an `Option<String>` instead: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b2e5c2fbd56ebe9996b4e79bc8e3da9).)

---

Lastly, if this config file reading is only done once at the start of your application, and the config is kept around for the rest of its lifetime, I think it is entirely reasonable to obtain a `&'static str` (which allows to deserialize to a `ConfigModel<'static>`) by using `Box::leak(read_to_string(…)?.into_boxed_str())`. (If this is in a library, you might want to protect against accidental repeated calls with a `static` `std::sync::Once` or similar.)

Comment: thanks so much again! This is why I love the Rust community, they are so helpful and I learn something new every day. I think wrapping the logic with a struct (defined as `ConfigReader` above) is a really great approach, and I was able to try with the `ConfigReader::read()?.deserialize()?` approach as mentioned, as well as the one with `new()`. I would never have thought of that and I think creating a struct to take ownership of a `String` field is ideally the right way to go. The only downside I had was that It still involves a bit of boilerplate code in tests (since two calls needed)

Comment: Since I'm using this in examples and tests mainly, I found that my ultimate goal and mindset was just like "import a helper function, then call it, and bada bing bada boom!". Towards that end, I found that the `Box::leak` and `into_boxed_str()` approach to convert the result of `read_to_string()?` into a `&str` value worked really well. In fact I think that was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. I added an answer to better illustrate the working solution I came up with, and was able to test that it works perfectly and exactly as I had envisioned or wanted it to.