# Rust lifetime issue when deserializing data

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde

I am writing a generic function to deserialize a type from a JSON file using `serde_json`. Unfortunately, I am struggling with lifetimes. The compiler complains that the string in which I temporarily store the data before I deserialize to the generic type does not live long enough.

This is my function:

```
use std::path::Path;
use serde::Deserialize;

fn load_data<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(location: &str) -> Result<T, &'a str> {

    let data_path = Path::new(&location);
    let mut data = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open(&data_path).expect("Unable to open file stream.");
    f.read_to_string(&mut data).expect("Unable to read file to string.");

    let result: T = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to deserialize data.");
    Ok(result)
}
```

And this is the error message from the compiler:

```
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src/templates/card_service_templates.rs:21:42
   |
14 | fn load_data<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(location: &str) -> Result<T, &'a str> {
   |              -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
21 |     let result: T = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to deserialize data.");
   |                     ---------------------^^^^^-
   |                     |                    |
   |                     |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                     argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'a`
22 |     Ok(result)
23 | }
   | - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Could the issue be that `data` needs to outlive the function?

Comment: Does using [`T: DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) instead of `T: Deserialize` help?

Comment: https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html

Comment: If you don't wan't `DeserializeOnwed`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379769/how-to-write-a-function-to-return-deserialized-struct-from-a-toml-file/73381857#73381857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`T: DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) as suggested worked out well. This is the adjusted version of my code:

```
use std::path::Path;
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

fn load_data<'a, T: DeserializeOwned>(location: &str) -> Result<T, &'a str> {

    let data_path = Path::new(&location);
    let mut data = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open(&data_path).expect("Unable to open file stream.");
    f.read_to_string(&mut data).expect("Unable to read file to string.");

    let result: T = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to deserialize data.");
    Ok(result)
}
```

The actual type only needs to derive `Deserialize`, e.g.

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyType {
  ...
}
```